# Java - formatear fecha desde Integer a String

Tags: java, date-format, localdate

Debo dar formato a una fecha que recibo en formato Integer yyyyMMdd a un String dd/MM/yyyy

Ejemplo: `Integer fecha = 20220801` -> `String fechaFormateada = 01/08/2022`

He intentado hacerlo con la api de Java "DateTime", pero me confunde mucho el hecho de recibir un Integer y, las pruebas que hice, no resultaron.

Me podrán ayudar?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has investigado / intentado y qué dificultades tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: Pista: descompón la fecha en sus partes. Luego puedes darle la forma que quieras. No es muy difícil.

Comment: @Mateo , decís que del mismo Integer obtenga cada dato de la fecha para luego manejarlos directo con la api DateTime?

Comment: Revisa [`SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse).

Comment: @Fernando claro. O si prefieres puedes concatenar cada uno en un string directamente. `String fecha = día + "/" + mes + "/" + año`

Comment: Para la próxima, no guardes una fecha en Integer... Por ejemplo: ¿qué pasará si el año llega a ser menor a 1000?

Comment: @padaleiana es muy normal trabajar con las fechas como integer en java por lo visto. En el trabajo lo hacen mucho también... a mi al principio no me gustaba pero lo cierto es que si son fechas actuales, nunca vas a tener problemas con ellas por lo menos en los próximos 7978 años, más o menos :)

Comment: @Benito-B Lo sé... Llegué también a cometer esas barbaridades (?

Comment: @padaleiana Es que me pasa como dicen más arriba... en el trabajo usan tablas que ya están diseñadas y hay que usarlas como están...

Answer (score 2):

Listo... adopté una solución rápida y ahí va mi método:

```
String fechaFormateada(Integer fecha) {
    String fechaString = fecha.toString();
    String anio = fechaString.substring(0, 4);
    String mes = fechaString.substring(4, 6);
    String dia = fechaString.substring(6, 8);
    return dia + "/" + mes + "/" + anio;
}
```

Siempre teniendo en cuenta mi formato de entrada como un `Integer` del tipo `yyyyMMdd`

Gracias a todos por sus prontas respuestas y prometo leer bien la documentación que me recomendaron.